# php get random unique value from an array without repeating & also preserve & get the key

Tags: php, arrays

I am new to php, I am trying to get random value from an array of lets say 4 values without repeating the value for the array group & also get the key for that values . I have multiple places on page where i echo the value . i tried `array_rand` , `shuffle()` but they repeat the values not keeping uniques.

```
$fruit = [
'f1' => 'mango',
'f2' => 'pear',
'f3' => 'apple',
'f4' => 'banana',
];
$key = array_keys($fruit);
$fruitvalue = $key[shuffle($key)];
```

echo `$key` & `$fruitvalue`   somewhere on page

Shuffle() , array_rand() isnt helping me keep the values unique in a single cycle of 4 if i want the random values to appear 120 times on page
also i cant use i=1;i<120;i++ as that "120" is not fixed ,on some places its 150 while different at other pages ..
IF i want to show random value at 120 places , these values should be unique  in each group of 4 but a same time random and so on in each successive group so 1st group [i.e. 1st 4 values] in list of 120 can have random but be unique like pear,banana,apple,mango then next 4 can be again random but unique ie. no repeat & so on till end...I also echo they key infront of the value so that too needs to be preserved . How do i achieve it ?

Comment: You'll only have 4! (=24) combinations, so there will be some repetition?

Comment: You want to output the `f1`, `f2` etc. values as well?

Comment: What are you using as a counter when you output the values?

Comment: @LTPCGO  yes repetiton will be there but i dont want it in the group of 4 , lets say we have 20 places where want to echo `$fruitvalue`  so we can divide 20 into five groups of 4 ; in each group all the four will be there & no repeat which shuffle() or array_rand() does..i want to achieve unique with no repeat and also be able to call the $key as its too beign echoed

Comment: @Nick yes so lets say echoed `$fruitvalue` was mango , i also get f1 by echoing $key

Comment: @simon but statistical given a small n to shuffle, then over a period x and given a large number of groups N there will be repetition. If you don't want that then you need to specify it in the code somehow.

Comment: @LTPCGO  check out the answer given below by Nick ,  something like that but we want echo just one variable..there will be say 120 places where this variable will automatcially appear , this 120 is not fixed, in some pages its 150 in soem its just 10,etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to achieve your desired result is to write a function which returns a random value from the `$fruit` array, going through all values in the array and then shuffling the array before returning the next set of values. Since we can't [`shuffle`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php) an array without losing the keys, this function stores the keys of the `$fruit` array and shuffles them instead:

```
function random_fruit() {
    static $i = 0;
    static $fruit = [
        'f1' => 'mango',
        'f2' => 'pear',
        'f3' => 'apple',
        'f4' => 'banana',
    ];
    // would be nice to write:
    //   static $keys = array_keys($fruit); 
    // but PHP doesn't allow it so we have to assign the value
    // the first time we call the function
    static $keys;
    if ($i == 0) $keys = array_keys($fruit);
    $length = count($fruit);
    if ($i % $length == 0) shuffle($keys);
    return array($keys[$i % $length], $fruit[$keys[$i++ % $length]]);
}
```

Then every time you want a new fruit, you can simply call the `random_fruit` function. For example, to output 20 random fruits:

```
for ($j = 0; $j < 20; $j++) {
    list($key, $fruitvalue) = random_fruit();
    echo "$key: $fruitvalue\n";
    if ($j % 4 == 3) echo "-----\n";
}
```

Sample output:

```
f4: banana
f2: pear
f1: mango
f3: apple
-----
f4: banana
f1: mango
f3: apple
f2: pear
-----
f3: apple
f2: pear
f4: banana
f1: mango
-----
f3: apple
f1: mango
f4: banana
f2: pear
-----
f4: banana
f1: mango
f2: pear
f3: apple
-----
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/sb2aO)

Comment: thank you Nick , i already have a function in which i include that code ..In your code i think i get limited by $j< 20 as i can have more than 20 values..inthose case how do we fix the code ? in the end we just want 2 variables $key & $fruitvalue which would be used at different places to echo the output

Comment: @Simon I just used a loop to demo the code. You can call that function as many times as you like and it will keep returning random fruits in groups of 4 as the sample output shows.

Comment: In other words, every time you want a new fruit, just put `list($key, $fruitvalue) = random_fruit();` in your code.

Comment: thank you @Nick i am sorry i am new to this, i am not able to get my head around the `list($key, $fruitvalue) = random_fruit();`  you mentioned. I understand what you meant is simply calling that function & i suppose it should give me a list but i just want a single random value . When this php code runs on the page it will check every of the 120 places & echo  the random $fruitvalue & its key which will be unique non repeating for group of 4 sequence until the end of page . .

Comment: therefore in our functions.php  i just need final $fruitvalue & $key . I already have  a custom function of which the above code is a part , what i want to achieve at end of your code too is get "$key";  & $fruitvalue;  & these 2 are then globally automatically added wherever they have their insertions so my first doubt was how can i combine the two functions or if is there need to combine two & instead directly replace my above code with yours as  i tried in this link - https://3v4l.org/TGZL6  but as we see i am doing some gross mistake .

Comment: Ultimately the whole function is such that when it reads the page and comes across no. 1 , it processes the php code & echoes & fills up the place for key & fruit value at 1st place , then 2nd place and so on...till the end .

Comment: @Simon the function `random_fruit()` returns an array with two values, the key and the fruit. `list($key, $fruitvalue) = random_fruit()` is just a shorthand way of writing `$array = random_fruit(); $key = $array[0]; $fruitvalue = $array[1];`

Comment: Hello Nick , sorry for late reply , i have a function related to anchor tags ```function ( $fmg ) {```  which has 2 parts , first part identifies "hyperlinks" , 2nd part [the code in question] does the shuffle of fruits & is inserted in the final part of code which  is ```$fmgfruits->set_attr( 'data-fruit-name', $fruitvalue );```   & ```$fmgfruits->set_attr( 'data-fruit-number', $key );```   as you can see the end part is just calling $key & $fruitvalue once , how do i achieve it using your code

Comment: Hi Simon - likewise, been on a short holiday. Something like this? https://3v4l.org/GNpP2

Answer (score 0):

I'd do something like this

```
$keys = shuffle(array_keys($fruit));
```

Then you could use array_shift to take the first element of the array while shortening the array.

```
$fruit1 = $fruit[array_shift($keys)];
$fruit2 = $fruit[array_shift($keys)];
$fruit3 = $fruit[array_shift($keys)];
$fruit4 = $fruit[array_shift($keys)];
```

[array_shift](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php)

Comment: but how do i get the `$fruitvalue` & $key ? since only these two will be used on the page

Comment: The output of `$fruit[array_shift($keys)]` will be the value of the fruit. 


If you need the key as well then store `array_shift($keys)` in a variable.


So `$fruitkey1 = array_shift($keys); $fruit1 = $fruit[$fruitkey1];`

Answer (score 0):

You can also do just:

```
$k = array_rand($fruit);
$v = $fruit[$k];
```

This is the way to do it when you have an associative array.

Comment: already did that too, the value gets duplicate in group of 4 , what i want to achieve is keep the values unique in set of 4 i.e. we dont want 2 mango in successive four values